# strcat does not work when trying to add a newline character to the end of a char array

Tags: c, char, strcat

I have a double pointer char array which will store rows of strings. My function is parsing a line read from a file and then stores each parsed item into a different file called "intermediate.txt". I want every item parsed to have a new line added to the end of its string so in the intermediate file every item parsed is on its own line.

I'm trying to use strcat and it seems to work fine with every row, except brokenUpLine[4]. (I'm purposely skipping the element at the 3rd index). brokenUpLine[4] at this point is currently storing "error codes". I want to add a newline at the end of the string and it keeps crashing. If I remove this line of code, it works fine but crashes when I add it. Can someone help me out and explain why this is crashing. Here's the code:

```
void assemblePass1(FILE * sourceF)
{
    int i;
    char line[260];
    char ** brokenUpLine;
    op * opCodes = createOPtable();     
    if (opCodes == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error allocating memory!\n\n");
        return;
    }

    char * fn = "intermediate.txt";
    FILE * imfp = checkForFileErrors(fn);
    if (imfp != NULL)
        imfp = fopen(fn, "w+");
    else
        return;                             

    while (fgets(line, 260, sourceF) != NULL)       //read line from source file
    {
        //write current source line to intermediate file
        fprintf(imfp, line);
        //breaks up line into values, write each value on new line in intermediate.txt
        brokenUpLine = breakUpLine(line);               //remember to free brokenUpLine
        strcat(brokenUpLine[0], "\n");
        strcat(brokenUpLine[1], "\n");
        strcat(brokenUpLine[2], "\n");
        strcat(brokenUpLine[4], "\n");          //*crashes at this line*
        fprintf(imfp, brokenUpLine[0]);         //write label to file
        fprintf(imfp, brokenUpLine[1]);         //write opcode to file
        fprintf(imfp, brokenUpLine[2]);         //write operand to file
        fprintf(imfp, brokenUpLine[3]);         //write comments to file
        fprintf(imfp, brokenUpLine[4]);         //write error code to file

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            brokenUpLine[i] = NULL;
            free(brokenUpLine[i]);
        }

        free(brokenUpLine);
        break;              //for testing
    }

    free(opCodes);
    fclose(imfp);
    printf("Opening file was a success!\n\n");
}
```

Here's breakUpLine():

```
char ** breakUpLine(char * line)
{
    int row = 5, cols = 150, i;
    char * string = NULL;
    char ** arr = (char**)malloc(row * sizeof(char*));  //allocate 5 rows of memory (label(0), opcode(1), operand(2), comment(3), error code(4))
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        arr[i] = (char*)malloc(cols * sizeof(char));    //allocates 150 columns to store a string per row

    char * token = NULL;
    i = 0;

    if (line[0] == ' ')                 //if there is no label, assign to the label row an empty space
    {
        arr[0] = " ";                   //store a space in label column to indicate it has no label
        i = 1;
    }

    token = strtok(line, " \t");        //get first token; break up by spaces or tabs
    if (token[0] == '.')                    //if a period is found at beginning of line, then the line is an entire comment
    {
        token = strtok(NULL, "\n");     //store entire comment sentence including the spaces, so update token delimeter to a newline character
        arr[0] = ".";
        arr[1] = "\n";
        arr[2] = "\n";
        arr[3] = token;                 //store comment in comment row
        arr[4] = NULL;                  //error code will be 0 or NULL if no error was detected
        return arr;                     //remember to free arr in assemblePass1()
    }

    arr[i++] = token;                   //store token in appropriate row
    while (token != NULL && i != 3)     
    {
        token = strtok(NULL, " \t");
        arr[i++] = token;
        //totest:printf("%s\n", arr[i-2]);
    }

    //totest:printf("%s\n", arr[i - 1]);
    token = strtok(NULL, "\t");     //process comments
    arr[i] = token;                 //store comment in comment column
    arr[4] = "Error code";                  //error code will go here

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Whatever `breakUpLine` does, it may be allocating not enough memory. it presumably happens to work for the other parts because you are writing into memory after that, which may just be some space "in between". So please show `breakUpLine`.

Comment: Unrelated to the crash, but your cleanup code should `free(brokenUpLine[i])` *before* setting `brokenUpLine[i] = NULL;`.

Comment: @Jongware I added `breakUpLine()`.

Comment: @keithmo it crashes if I do it that way :/ I'm a noobie to C.

Comment: It crashes because you're calling `free()` on pointers that were not returned from `malloc()`. You can't call `free()` on static strings such as "\n", etc.

Comment: @keithmo ok but I'm returning a pointer that was allocated using malloc when I call `breakUpLine` and storing that pointer in `brokenUpLine`. Do I have to call malloc on this pointer too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You crash because of this line:

```
    arr[4] = NULL;                  //error code will be 0 or NULL if no error was detected
```

since you subsequently try to `strcat` to this `NULL` pointer here:

```
    strcat(brokenUpLine[4], "\n");          //*crashes at this line*
```

Maybe this was meant to be:

```
    strcat(brokenUpLine[3], "\n");
```

???

You also have problems here:

```
    arr[0] = ".";
    arr[1] = "\n";
    arr[2] = "\n";
```

These should be:

```
    strcpy(arr[0], ".");
    strcpy(arr[1], "\n");
    strcpy(arr[2], "\n");
```

otherwise you have (a) Undefined behaviour when you try to `strcat` to these strings, (b) three memory leaks and (c ) even more undefined behaviour if you later try to `free()` these strings.

Comment: Ah thanks! Also, why is the assignment wrong? Why should I be using strcpy? Thanks, I'm new to C so I want to learn these things.

Comment: You can't assign strings with `=` in C - you can only assign *pointers*, which is what you're doing in your code. So this effectively throws away the original memory allocation (which is a memory leak) and replaces the pointer with a pointer to s string literal. TL;DR: use `strcpy` to assign strings in C, not `=`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clearing this up for me. I'll fix the code :]